# Need help optimizing for loop in large webscraping task

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, sampling

I am working on a solo project that starts with generating stock data using the **rvest** package for webscraping and storing it in a datatable.

The loop pulls a portion of the stock tickers from a website and stores it in a dataframe. My code is *extremely* archaic (I think), partly because of the way the website is organized. The website arranges the symbols on pages alphabetically, with a different number of tickers on each page (1 page per letter) - yes I had to count how many per page. What I ended up with works but runs extremely slowly:

```
#GET AMEX tickers
alphabet <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K',
          'L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V',
          'W','X','Y','Z')
#start at 2
lengths <- c(65,96,89,125,161,154,86,62,173,83,26,43,62,51,
         37,126,25,81,149,52,77,74,34,50,8,11)

amexurls <- paste0("http://findata.co.nz/markets/AMEX/symbols/",toupper(alphabet),".htm",
 sep = "")

iterator <- 0
for(j in 1:26){
  url <- amexurls[j]
  for(k in 2:lengths[j]){

html <- read_html(as.character(url))
iterator 
test <- html_nodes(html,as.character(paste0("tr:nth-child(",k,") a")))
test <- toString(test)
test <-  gsub("<[^>]+>", "", test)
amexsymbols[k-2+iterator] <- test

  }
  iterator <- iterator + lengths[j] + 1
}
```

The for loop above takes over an hour to run. I think it may be mainly because of the many calls to the internet.

I'm trying to get better about understanding vectorization and other tricks to maximize R's efficiency, especially on a big project like this.

Things I've tried/seen:

-I have taken as much out of the body of the loop (the paste0 line specifically

-Switching from dataframe to datatable

-In a much older post, user @Gregor (thanks again) showed me I can take advantage of paste0 being a vectorized function, and hence *amexurls* doesn't use a for loop to store - but unfortunately this isn't the slow part of the code

This is just a snippit of much a much larger web scraping code. If I can optimize this chunk, I can apply it to the rest. Any improvements to my code or tips/tricks would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: where does `amexsymbols` come from?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `rvest`).

Comment: Why is `html <- read_html()` in the inner loop? As an example, when `j` is `1`, then `url` is the `".../A.htm"` version, and `k` varies from 2 to 65. But `url` doesn't change, so that means you are calling `read_html` on the same URL 64 times. That's *probably* your slowest step. Move it to the outer loop.

Comment: In general, though, don't guess about what's taking a long time. [Profile your code](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html). Switching from data frame to data.table probably saved you less than 0.01 seconds per iteration. Using `paste0` once makes your code easier to read, but saves even less time. Profiling will identify the pieces that actually *are* taking a long time so you don't have to guess.

Comment: Other minor things (won't help speed, but will improve readability and quality of life): use the built-in `LETTERS` instead of defining your own `alphabet`. Both `LETTERS` and `alphabet` are upper case already, so don't call `toupper` on them. `paste` and `paste0` always return `character`, so you don't need to call `as.character()` on your `url`.

Comment: to add to @Gregor, if you use `paste0()` then you can remove `sep = ""` since that what `paste0()` does.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the support again. These tricks are new to me and I have combined them with Matt's post below and the result is much more potent code. Next step, cleaning the data and running it through some multiclass neural nets.

Comment: @dylanjm amexsymbols is the table where the stock symbols should be stored once they are pulled from the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this right now, due to firewall restrictions. But I would recommend trying something using the `html_table()` function from `rvest` to collect the data. It would be much more dynamic than manually specifying the number of stocks on each page, and looping through each row individually.

```
library(rvest)

amexurls <- paste0("http://findata.co.nz/markets/AMEX/symbols/", LETTERS,".htm")

ldf <- list()
iterator <- 0

for(url in amexurls){
  iterator <- iterator + 1
  html <- read_html(url)
  ldf[[iterator]] <- html_table(html_nodes(html, "table")[[2]])
}

df <- do.call(rbind, ldf)
```

Comment: Matt, this is excellent. It is nice to pull, quickly, all of info from the page. It's like you pull everything first, and trim it within R later. Very elegant to store a lists of lists, and then combine those sublists into a single data frame. Ran in just a few minutes.